# Does node.js has 'match()' method? If so what is the syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried using `.match()` method in node.js and the console returns `has no method 'match'`. This is the part where I call the method:

```
fs.readFile('proxy.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (data.match('\n').length < proxyNum) {
        proxyNum = data.match('\n').length;
    }
    console.log('Testing ' + proxyNum + 'proxies.');
});
```

Any idea how I could properly call `.match()`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `data` is a `Buffer`: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html, https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback

Comment: @thefourtheye determine the length of `'\n'` in `data`.

Comment: @FelixKling I see! So I should turn it into string first...

Comment: @FelixKling Can you make it an answer? I will close the question.

Comment: @AeroWindwalker length of `\n` is always `1`. What am I missing?

Comment: @thefourtheye Sorry, I meant I am trying to determine the number of `\n` in `data`.

Comment: Just use `utf-8` like this: `fs.readFile('proxy.txt', 'utf-8', function (err, data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got two problems here:

1. `fs.readFile` returns data as buffer, so you should use `var data = data.toString('utf-8')` to turn it into string.
2. You should use `data.match(/\n/g).length` to determine the length of the data or it will always return 0 or 1;